# Professional Titles for Engineer

Tags: word-choice, particles

I am setting up a Japanese language profile in LinkedIn. I am a Nuclear Engineer, but am unsure exactly how that profession is worded in japanese. 
The two options that seem most appropriate are:
原発の技師 
and
原子力の技師 
I know I can also use katakana to mimic the English words.  Which of thise is appropriate?

To include my company would it be: "[Company] で 原発の技師"

I would appreciate help fixing up these two issues. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you actually do.

- 原発 (short for 原子力発電所) refers only to a nuclear power plant. If your specialty is to design or install a large machine to generate electricity, 原子力発電技術者 makes sense.
- 原子力 is nuclear power. If your job is related only to producing energy (power plant, atomic battery, etc), you can use 原子力技術者.
- If your specialty is more generic and related also to nuclear medicine, cyclotrons, etc., then 核技術者 or 核工学者 should be better.

Also note that, since Japan has experienced several tragic episodes related to nuclear physics, both 核 and 原子力 often has a bad image among laypeople. You may want to consider something like 量子工学者 instead.

Comment: This is very helpful.  I especially appreciate your note about perception.  My concern about switching to 量子工学者 is in accurately representing my credentials.  It seems to translate to quantum engineer, which may seem related to a layperson, but is not truly related to traditional nuclear engineering.  Is the translation of 量子 more general than I'm understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Did a quick concordance search on google and came up with ~420k hits for 原子力技術者 and ~25k for 原発技術者. The former also pulled up hits on job websites, so I'd go with that for your LinkedIn.

You have a couple options for how to say where you work. You can say [Company]の原子力技術者, but I've also seen [occupation]@[Company] a lot of social media like Twitter.

Comment: Thank you vel!  This is most helpful!

Comment: Google hit counts are basically random numbers, they unfortunately can’t be used reliably for this sort of comparison.